# How to add Alignment(left Align, center align, right align) toolbar in Summernote Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am doing some POC on summernote HTML Editor and i am using custom toolbar but i am not getting how to add the Alignment(left Align, center align, right align) tollbar, so someone can help me to achieve this.

Also can sombody help me to find some more HTML bootstrap editor which i can use as free?

Comment: I think you can achieve this using `text-align` css property..

Comment: Are you wanting to just align text, or actually align html elements like you would see in Illustrator or any other design program?

Comment: @Jonathan: looking for html elements like other design program(like ms word), i find in other HTML editor easily but not getting in Summernote Html editor

Comment: @Rayon: I am looking toolbar in Summernote HTML Editor

Answer (score 2):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        tabsize: 2,
        direction: 'rtl'
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I setup basic summernote like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                $('.summernote').summernote({
                    height: 500,
                    toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['font', ['bold', 'underline', 'clear']],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]
                ],
```

Note the line "['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']]".

This gives me toolbar like:

[image]